# Php fetch returns string and not boolean "true/false" value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

I'm using full calender and I have a few events that are all day events. Generally, my php set all `'allDay' => 'false'`. Now that I noticed it adds a time on it if I do not specify a time.

I want to set all defaults false for all values, unless I specify them true.

My php fetch is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `time`, `start`, `end`, `url`, `backgroundColor`, `textColor`, `className`,
   `allDay` FROM calender WHERE length('column') > '0'";

$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $row){
    $return[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],
                'title'=>$row['title'],
                "allDay" =>$row['allDay'],
                'start'=>$row['start'].' '.$row['time'],
                'end'=>$row['end'],
                'url'=>$row['url'],
                'backgroundColor'=>$row['backgroundColor'],
                'textColor'=>$row['textColor'],
                'className' =>$row['className']);
}
$dbh = null;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

and the jQuery function is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    events: "json-events.php", 
    eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(You cannot update these fields!)');
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        },
    });
});
```

I do not know where I add the values. I have mySQL storing 'allDay' as true/false but it returns as a string. So I actually know how to go about coverting it before json encodes the file. or have jQuery/javascript change it after the data is being looked at.

Comment: Why do you have `allDay` twice in the array? Also you're mixin single and double quotes all over the place, not a good habit..

Comment: That's funny, I was trying to fix it and never actually went back and erased the last one.

Comment: What column type are you using to store the true/false values?

Comment: @liquorvicar tinyint. i read that stores values at boolean values not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type is the allDay field in MySQL? If it's an `enum('true', 'false')`, that's probably your problem. That gets converted to a string. I've had people do this, and it took me forever to figure out why what I thought was a boolean (or an int) was a string.

Double check your database and try making it a `tinyint(1)` and using 0 for false and 1 for true. PHP's boolean true and false will get casted to the corresponding integers and you won't have a problem using 0/1 in JavaScript.

Comment: If i do that, then I need to edit my javascript to say if its string leave as is and if its a true/false return the value?

Comment: If done correctly, you should be able to just evaluate it as true or false. Try doing a var_dump on return before json_encode in your PHP to list all of the types and values of the array, so we know for sure what type allDay is.

Comment: var_dump says ["allDay"]=> string(1) "1"

Comment: That's different... well, try "allDay" => intval($row['allDay']) or "allDay" => $row['allDay'] == "1". The former will convert string(1) "1" to int(1) which will evaluate true.

Comment: Very nice work. It worked. I'll test a bit more and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($result as $row){
    $return[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],
                'title'=>$row['title'],
                "allDay" =>$row['allDay'] == "true",
                'start'=>$row['start'].' '.$row['time'],
                'end'=>$row['end'],
                'url'=>$row['url'],
                'backgroundColor'=>$row['backgroundColor'],
                'textColor'=>$row['textColor'],
                'className' =>$row['className']);
}
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: it actually gave me the right values, but is still showing it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could allso try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `time`, `start`, `end`, `url`, `backgroundColor`, `textColor`, `className`, IF(`allDay` = 'true',true,false) AS allDay  FROM calender WHERE length('column') > '0'";
```